# Seperate js File utf-8 not working in ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a textBox. When I click mybtn if myTxtBox is empty a tooltip appears and give the message which attached to 'data-original-title'. It's working fine but when I add turkish charachters inside text instead of "Some text", these charachters are shown as a question mark.

```
$("#mybtn").on('click', function (e) {
if ($("#myTxtBox").val() == "") {
                MyTooltipCreator("#myTxtBox");
                $("#myTxtBox")
                    .attr('data-original-title', "Some text")
                    .tooltip('fixTitle')
                    .tooltip('show');
            }
 });
```

The strange thing is when I add my scripts inside my cshtml file it works very well. The problem occurs after I move my scripts into a seperate js file.

Comment: There can be several reasons behind this. What is document type? If you insert same Turkish character in plane <div> on page then does it shows? Does the font supports those Unicode characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is a static text then I think you need to change your js file Encoding Type.

> Open your js file in Visual Studio. Click to "File" from top left
>   corner. Then click to "Save as" your file.  There is an arrow next to
>   the "Save" button. Click to this arrow and select "Save with Encoding"
>   and confirm the Save as process. In "Advanced Save Options" popup
>   select Unicode(UTF-8) Encoding and click "OK".

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: How it will help?

Comment: you can set specific character encoding. it worked for me.

Comment: So you mean this line .attr('data-original-title', "TurikishCharacter")
contains static text?

Comment: @Amit as in the sample, yes.

Comment: @umtc Can you test with dynamic.