# Browsers show German alphabets as ? in asp.net mvc application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am localizing an application into German language. German for Delete is Löschen but browser shows ö as ?. The string comes from .js file made in jquery. Visual Studio IDE recognizes the character but browser does not.

The string resource that come from the resx file do not exhibit the issue. This issue is only for js files.

I tried adding German language to my Chrome but the still the issue persists. I also tried installing Deutsh to my Windows 10 machine also.

Anyone, please help.

Comment: Is it displayed in the debugger correct? Do you use UTF-8?

Comment: Yes. In _Layout.cshtml ,<meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: Probably your JS File isn't uft-8 encoded? Does it send an UTF-8 header? Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42158297/2441442) helps you. In case, please mark your question as duplicate of it using *flag*.